Dynatrace OneAgent Pod Failing with CrashLoopBackOff in Kubernetes Cluster on Docker Desktop
I am encountering an issue with the Dynatrace OneAgent pod in my Kubernetes cluster, which is provided by Docker Desktop. The pod dynatrace-montor-1-oneagent-jdpfs is in a CrashLoopBackOff state, while the dynatrace-oneagent-csi-driver-dx5pv pod is running without issues. The error logs indicate:
Error: Cannot determine volume host path from /proc/self/mountinfo: /data/kubelet/plugins/csi.oneagent.dynatrace.com/data/cfq65015/osagent does not exist on the host
Steps Taken:

Verified CSI Driver: The CSI driver pod (dynatrace-oneagent-csi-driver-dx5pv) is running without issues.
Checked Host Path: I checked the existence of the directory /data/kubelet/plugins/csi.oneagent.dynatrace.com/data/cfq65015/osagent on the host and it does not exist.
Pod and DaemonSet Configurations: The configurations for both the OneAgent and CSI driver DaemonSets are set correctly, and there are no apparent errors in the configuration files.


Consider to ask sys-admin questions (e.g. about installation of pre-made software) on https://serverfault.com instead. Stack Overflow is for programming questions.
